# Fontforge: Glyphs importing from inkscape with path inverted

Tags: inkscape, path, font-forge

When I import an svg from inkscape into fontforge, the path is inverted. Why is this?

I am running windows 10, with inkscape 0.91. When I try to import a glyph outline, fontforge imports it, but does so with 3 separate paths, and when viewed in the metrics window, it seems the path itself is inverted. Why is fontforge splitting 1 path into 3, and how can I prevent it from doing that?

pic1 - Fontforge metrics.

pic2 - tripled path after importing from inkscape

pic3 - full glyph

[image: The outline is inverted][image: The path is tripled. I COULD delete all the extra paths, but it would be nicer just to import the glyph without funky things like this happening. There are not 3 individual paths when I draw it in inkscape][image: The full glyph after being imported from inkscape]

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Can you please [edit] your question to elaborate your problem in more detail? At the very least, show the object you want to import and the result, and describe what is not satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a stroke set on your letter form. In Inkscape just remove the stroke before you save the SVG.

Example 1: importing an SVG into FontForge with stroke and fill set in Inkscape. The result is three paths.

[image]

Example 2: importing an SVG into FontForge with only fill applied, and no stroke in Inkscape. The result is a single path.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This looks familiar, if are are importing the objects from inkscape. 0.48 into pre-2015 builds of fontforge this happens. You should try to be very clear on the platform you are using eg.windows, mac or Linux distribution you are guaranteed a more defined solution. As a workaround in your case I would export the entire glyph set as png, convert it as an index png in whatever image editing tool you're using , load that png into a tool called glyphtracer, that will then output the image as a sfd you can open in fontforge for tweaking.